# Modal slide in and slide out after X click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I hope someone will help me.

I have a `div` with `span`, this `span` after when gets clicked triggers modal which slides in from the right to the center, however I don't know how to make closing procedure with the sliding reverse animation ? so basically when you click on the close button it will slide out off the container.

[codepen source from W3C MODAL](https://codepen.io/igor-galicki/pen/LBYQgQ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="section start-project-home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="project-wrap">
        <h2>Want start project ?</h2>
        <p><span id="btnhomeModal" class="modal-click-send-home">send</span> a request </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="contact-form-heading-modal">
<h6>How may I help you?</h6>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, pariatur fugiat iusto voluptatem officiis eaque expedita aliquam ea nesciunt impedit minus? Rerum beatae vel provident hic quidem autem corporis unde.</p>
</div>

<form class="form-block" action="https://formspree.io/@gmail.com"
      method="POST">
<div class="subject-wrap">
        <label>Interested In...</label>
    <select class="closed-selection" name="Subject">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-wrapper-l">
      <label>Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name">  
</div>  

<div class="form-wrapper-r">
<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="email" name="_replyto">
</div>

<div class="bottom-contact-wrap">
<label>Description</label>
    <textarea class="desc-modal" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
    </div>

</form>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size:16px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;

}



/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}




/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
margin: 0 auto;
    height: 170vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    width: 65%;
    float: right;
    background: #fff;
     animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.45s
}

.modal-card, .modal-content {
      max-height: 100vh !important;
    width: 65vw !important;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Animation */
@keyframes animatetop {
    from {right: -1200px;}
    to {right: 0;}
}

.project-wrap {
  text-align: center;
    font-size: 61px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.project-wrap h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.modal-click-send-home {
  text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #3f3fff;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.modal-click-send-home:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.contact-form-heading-modal {
  margin: 245px auto 35px 2.5vw;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-form-heading-modal h6 {
      font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000;
}

.contact-form-heading-modal p {
      font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.form-block {
width: 100%;
}

.form-wrapper-modal {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}


.subject-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 58px;
    line-height: 58px;
}

.form-wrapper-l {
  width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
}

.form-block {
  font-size:21px;
}
```

script from W3C

```
  // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btnhomeModal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

See ? after when I click `X` or somewhere else this contact form just disappears, how can I make it slide out after when the `X` is clicked?

Thank you so much for help. I appreciate any help from you guys !

Regards,

Comment: Are you using JQuery?

Comment: Yes, however I would like prefer JavaScript - do you have solution? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply transition to the modal to slide in and slide out,

Add a class and remove a class on the open and close operations.

For a Transition to work the element should be present and the display property should be visible. try changing the position of the modal, if you want to slide left set the default position to right: -100% when close and change the position to right:0 on open.

Refer the codepen link below 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjzJyx

js

```
modal.classList.add("open")

modal.classList.remove("open")
```

Comment: Thank you, however this doesn't work - when you click "X" the modal stays on it place.

Comment: Sorry Igor I had pasted a wrong link to the codepen its updated now. Use the logic to add and remove a class to get the transition effect.  
link : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjzJyx